# How to emulate this layout in CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to replace an HTML form (created by tables) with list items to simplify the markup and to enable dynamic visibility (so I can reuse the control in different pages) of some items.  Essentially, I'd like to set the container div's max-height and then have any list items wrap to the right column after that point (using IE9 as the default browser).

[image: Form Layout]

I'm trying the following CSS:

```
ul.test {float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 1em 0;list-style: none;}
ul.test li {float: left; width: 49%;}
```

and HTML:

```
<div>
   <ul class="list2col">
    <li>
        <label>Project Name</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Project Launch Name</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Project Description</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Category</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Sub-Category</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Global Brand Concept</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Local Brand</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Activity Type</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Stage</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Status</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Innovation Type</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Innovation Sub Type</label><input style="float:right;"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But it doesn't look quite right:

[image]

I can't find many resources for this that use plain HTML and CSS (compatible with IE9), rather they use JavaScript and/or CSS3 to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:right` from your input tag and apply `width` and `inline-block` for your labels.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="test">
<li>
    <label>Project Name</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Project Launch Name</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Project Description</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Category</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Sub-Category</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Global Brand Concept</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Local Brand</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Activity Type</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Stage</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Status</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Innovation Type</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Innovation Sub Type</label><input type="text"/>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul.test {float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 1em 0;list-style: none;}
 ul.test li {float: left; width: 49%;}
 ul.test li label{width:150px; display:inline-block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/8tv03fmb/)